# How to debug JVM hanging on exit occasionally

Tags: java, jvm, freeze

I have a server that occasionally hangs when it exits.  The hang only occures about 1/10 or less of the time and so far we can't figure out a way to reliably recreate the issue.  I've walked through my code and thought that I am closing all resources and killing my threads, but obviously some of the time I don't close right.

Can anyone suggest debugging tips to help me test this when I can't reliably recreate it?  I've tried running JVisualVM once it goes down, but it doesn't help much other then showing me the sigterm threads are running still and everything is at 0% CPU, which I assume means a deadlock somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the process hangs you can send SIGQUIT (kill -3) to the process and it will generate a thread dump. The output goes to stderr so make sure that is being captured.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) to monitor your server. You can visually monitor the memory, CPU usages and no of threads etc. It also can detect deadlocks if there are.

Comment: If that doesn't work, start it with JPDA enabled and when it hangs connect with an IDE debugger and look for hung non-daemon threads.